# Does anyone know how to impose counters on status bar notifications in Honeycomb

Tags: android, notifications, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am trying to use number field of Notification class to get "number of events" associated with each notification. For Ex. If I have two unread emails, email icon in the status bar should show "2" imposed on the email icon. I think this was working fine with froyo but somehow I am not able to make it work for Honeycomb. This is how my code looks like

```
PendingIntent contentIntent;
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

builder.getNotification().number = 2; 
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.phone_missedcall);
builder.setTicker("ABCD & Status : Missed Call");
notificationIntent = new Intent (this, NotificationSBActivity.class);
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.contact_image, R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.line_name, "Line 2: Cisco");
builder.setContent(contentView);
```

But it doesn't show "2" imposed over the icon. Is there any other way to get the counter in Honeycomb ?? 
Also, tried

```
int icon = R.drawable.phone_app;        // icon from resources
CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";              // ticker-text
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
Context context = getApplicationContext();      // application Context
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";  // message title
CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";      // message text

notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationSBActivity.class);
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

// the next two lines initialize the Notification, using the configurations above
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
notification.number = 2;
mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Please let me know if anyone has tried notification counters on Honeycomb ??